# Jframe: No entiendo porque mi ventana se muestra achicada

Tags: java, jframe

Soy nuevo en Java (empece ayer xd), estoy aprendiendo JFrame para hacer aplicaciones de escritorio, y hice una calculadora para empezar, logre hacerla gracias a un tutorial pero la ventana sale muy achicada, no entiendo porque:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Por que pasa eso? (perdon si quiza doy poca informacion, soy novato jeje)

Uso JDK 15, Apache NetBeans IDE 12.5

EDIT: Aqui esta todo el codigo generado automaticamente por NetBeans (es una calculadora)

```
package javaapplication1;

public class Calculadoramain extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Calculadoramain() {
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        CajaNum2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        CajaNum1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        BotonTotal = new javax.swing.JButton();
        CajaTotal = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
        jPanel1.setLayout(null);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel1.setText("Numero 2:");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel1);
        jLabel1.setBounds(-70, 180, 580, 130);

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel2.setText("    Calculadora");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel2);
        jLabel2.setBounds(50, 0, 580, 130);

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jLabel3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel3.setText("Numero 1:");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel3);
        jLabel3.setBounds(-70, 120, 580, 130);

        CajaNum2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        CajaNum2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                CajaNum2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(CajaNum2);
        CajaNum2.setBounds(340, 230, 200, 40);

        CajaNum1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        CajaNum1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                CajaNum1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(CajaNum1);
        CajaNum1.setBounds(340, 160, 200, 40);

        BotonTotal.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        BotonTotal.setText("RESULTADO");
        BotonTotal.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                BotonTotalMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        BotonTotal.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                BotonTotalActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(BotonTotal);
        BotonTotal.setBounds(250, 390, 190, 40);

        CajaTotal.setEditable(false);
        CajaTotal.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                CajaTotalActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(CajaTotal);
        CajaTotal.setBounds(280, 440, 130, 40);

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setBounds(0, 0, 700, 529);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void CajaNum2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        
    }                                        

    private void CajaNum1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   
    }                                        

    private void BotonTotalActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    private void CajaTotalActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    private void BotonTotalMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
        int num1, num2, total;
        
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(CajaNum1.getText());
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(CajaNum2.getText());
        
        total = num1+num2;
        
        CajaTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));
    }                                       

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Calculadoramain().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton BotonTotal;
    private javax.swing.JTextField CajaNum1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField CajaNum2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField CajaTotal;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

EDIT: Ya lo he solucionado, en [JFrame] he puesto un AbsoluteLayout, y tambien lo he hecho en mi Panel de mi programa

Gracias a los comentarios, me han ayudado mucho ;)

Comment: No podemos adivinar qué problema tienes, ¿Cómo estás creado tu JFrame?, muestra tu código (escrito). lee acerca del [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Ahora mismo es como si mostrara un plato vacío y preguntara por qué la comida sabía mal

Comment: Ponle dimensiones, intenta con `setPreferredSize()` o `setBounds()`.

Comment: Ya esta, ya he puesto el codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falta ver como construyes el JFrame, pero esto suele suceder cuando se usa un `Layout` nulo sin tener tamaños en los componentes y en su ventana o por invocar el método `pack()` sin tener tamaños o administradores de diseño.

El `Layout` es quien decide como se reparten los componentes dentro de la ventana, este define la disposición de los componentes, y el tamaño de la ventana con relación al tamaño preferido de los componentes.

Cuando se usa layout nulo todo eso se va, por lo que se tiene que agregar siempre el tamaño y ubicación a todos los componentes manualmente, si no, la ventana se encogerá todo lo que pueda hasta ver un tamaño preferido.

Puedes intentar alguna de estas para solucionar el problema:

```
- setSize(width, height);
- setBounds(x, y, width, height)
- setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height))
```

Da un tamaño a los componentes, ya que no hay Layout que calcule esto, si el problema sigue, agrega tamaño a la ventana, aprender a usar administradores de diseño seria lo correcto, pero al empezar con interfaces gráficas casi no los usan, esto porque al principio te limita bastante a la hora de hacer la UI, hasta que aprendas a usar bien los administradores de diseño.

Si quieres aprender un poco mas sobre esto, busca por ejemplo `FlowLayout`, `BorderLayout`, `GridLayout`, `BoxLayout`, existen muchos mas, pero siempre es lo mismo, basta con agregarlo a un contendedor, establecer un par de cosas, y hará su efecto, esto te hará avanzar mucho mas rápido y tener un diseños redimensionables.

Comment: recuerda que es un completo novato, yo le pondría ligas a la documentación :3